# Most energy efficient and very small volume way to produce motion

Tags: servo, motion

I'm looking to make motion (may be 100g) using very small, and very energy efficient component, and prefereably very cheap, i've found some nano servomotors which satisfy my criteria, but i wonder if there is any simple piece of hardware that acts like the old door bell.

Comment: A solenoid is what is used to strike the chime in door bells.

Comment: 100g as in move 100 grams, or 100g as in 100 times earth acceleration? My old door bell doesn't move at all - what are you thinking of? If you got devices satisfying your criteria, why don't you tell us your criteria in a better way or at least name devices which fulfil them?

Comment: Solenoids are good (in terms of low power) if you don't need to hold the position and can use jerky motion with significantly more force at the **end** of the stroke. Servos give more controlled smooth motion and may be able to hold position without drawing continuous power. Of course in relays the solenoid is powered continuously to hold the relay state (in most relays) so if you can spare that amount of power the solenoid is very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if you could give bit more explanation on your final goal. I'm not sure if you need linear or angular motion. In case of linear then, I'd go for solenoid, in other case, 9gr. servo should do the job. These servos are quite cheap and not so power hungry.

Comment: i was looking for Solenoid, but which one more energy effecient Solenoid VS nano servomotor ?